# domain name rent and static public IP

Tags: networking, dns

Suppose the "test" domain is free, and I want to rent it to a registrar. Also, I want on this domain to match a static public IP address. And I am interested not about a web server and web page. But only creating mail accounts such as a1@test.com , a2@test.com etc.

With the rent of domain from the registrar, I automatically get a static public IP address?

If not, where do I get the address and how will I make this address to show this domain?

And some other things on your opinions I should consider about all that?

Thank you!

Comment: Domain registration and domain hosting are two separate services. Registering a domain _only_ gets you the right to delegate the DNS records for this domain to a DNS server of your choice.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate anyway. Please document your efforts. What did you search for, and what did you find?

Comment: When you get a domain name, you get DNS services. You do not get an IP address. On the DNS you can then setup an A record which makes the domain name point to that IP Address. You still do need to own that IP Address though.

Answer (score 2):

You do not appear to understand what you're asking.

## Public IP Address

> With the rent of domain from the registrar, I automatically get a static public IP address?

No, that's not how it works.

If I translate your question to the real world, you are asking for a postal code and a door too, but you don't want a house.

A postal code can be linked to the door, yes. But you cannot get a door without the rest. The door is part of the house the same way an IP Address is part of an internet connection.

When you rent webspace, you are given an IP Address. When you get internet access at home, you are given an IP Address.

Yes, in some places it is possible to get a 2nd IP Address the same way it is possible to add a 2nd door to your house, but without the house and the first door, the 2nd door is as meaningless as the extra IP Address.

So in order to get a public IP Address that is static, you need to have something attached to it. The IP Address is only a connection point to an Internet service. If you want a static IP Address to connect to your own internet, then you need to buy a static IP Address from your ISP.

## Email hosting

You also talk about email, this requires an email server. Email hosting would give you an ip address, but they often also come with the ability to host websites. So basically, you really do want a website online, but you can choose to not use it.

A simple index.php as only page with the following content:

```php
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

will make it seem the website does not exist.

Alternatively you can use services such as Office365 or gmail. You then don't even need a public IP Address. All you do is set the MX record to your office365 account: eg: mydomain-ext.onmicrosoft.com or link the domain through gmail.

## DNS

The Domain name is completely separate from all this.

When you buy webhosting services, they often include a free domain name, because you need it anyway, and it is a marketing strategy because not every webhosting service gives you a free domainname too (most do nowadays, but not all).

The domainname is configured using DNS and all it does is link a name to an IP Address and have some additional settings.

Comment: Thank you all for your very informative answers! I am sorry if with my question it seems not to understand what my problem is and I do not understand what I am asking for, I will express it in other words, and hope this time help you understand my problem. What I wanna do is as following : I want to rent a free domain, e.g. test , and install locally a mail server for these @test accounts. There are too many terms on the whole situation: registrars, host,email hosting services,MSA,MTA, mail server (web mail server vs in-house mail server),activate mail account,and many more. Try to understand.

Comment: A domainname is just a small service that makes a name point to something else. You cannot rent a domainname that comes with just email, but you can probably rent an email server that comes with a domainname, or alternatively rent a domainname seperately, rent an Office365 subscription and in there add your domainname and say to Office: I want you to manage my DNS for me and it will link both together.